# SG3xx Password Reset/Recovery

Tags: cisco, switch, cli, cisco-sg300

Trying to reset a password for a number of switches I have. Didn't save the text file I had jotted it down in....of course.

Connected via serial, but cannot seem to locate any concise info on resetting a forgotten password via serial online.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cisco maintains documents for this type of thing. For your particular switch:

*[Administrator Password Recovery for 300 and 500 Series Managed Switches](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/switches/cisco-small-business-300-series-managed-switches/smb4985-administrator-password-recovery-for-300-and-500-series-manag.html)*

Comment: Ah, thank you. My Google fu was apparently too weak.